# JS style.marginLeft & marginRight = 'auto' not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the Yahoo Weather API.

When trying to set the style margins via JS, nothing happens.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
var cBackFunction = function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var location = data.query.results.channel.location;
    var condition = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
    var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind;
    var units = data.query.results.channel.units;
    var link = data.query.results.channel.link;
    var lastUpdated = data.query.results.channel.lastBuildDate;
    var conditionCode = condition.code;
    var conditionText = condition.text;

    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = "https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?a/i/us/we/52/" + conditionCode + ".gif";
    img.style.marginLeft = "140px";

    document.getElementById('Weather-Description2').appendChild(img);

    document.getElementById('Weather-Location2').innerHTML = location.city;
    document.getElementById('Weather-Region2').innerHTML = location.region;
    document.getElementById('Weather-Temp2').innerHTML = condition.temp;
    document.getElementById('Weather-Unit2').innerHTML = units.temperature;
    document.getElementById('Weather-WindSpeed2').innerHTML = wind.speed;
    document.getElementById('Weather-Link2').href = link;
    document.getElementById('lastUpdate2').innerHTML = lastUpdated;
    document.getElementById('Weather-text2').innerHTML = "["+conditionText+"]";
    document.getElementById('Weather-text2').style.marginLeft = 'auto';     //not working
    document.getElementById('Weather-text2').style.marginRight = 'auto';     // not working
}
```

HTML:

```
<strong id="Weather-text2"></strong>
```

If I change the `auto` to a specific pixel like *"100px"* then it works.. can `auto` be used in JS for margins?  The reason for `auto` on both `marginLeft` and `marginRight` is to auto-center the element. If so, how do I implement that correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<strong>` element is, by default, `display: inline`.

Auto margins centre elements which are `display: block` (although since you would have `width: auto` as the default, this would have no practical effect unless you also reduced the width).

Set `text-align: center` on the nearest block ancestor element to centre the text.

Comment: ahh that worked. if you don't mind telling me, how did you know that certain html elements are displayed inline and others are displayed block?

Comment: I read the HTML spec when it was [much simpler](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) then it is today.